# NOT IN function is not working on my version of mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this statement that works on mysql version `5.5.44-0` however it's not working at all in mysql `4.0.24`

Any ideas what I can change to make it backwards compatible?

```
select distinct cust_id
from billing where billing.cust_id
not in (
select distinct billing_id from internet
);
```

These are the tables

```
mysql> select * from billing;
+----+---------+-------+
| id | cust_id | cost  |
+----+---------+-------+
|  2 |      34 |   500 |
|  3 |      12 | 67700 |
|  4 |      99 |   100 |
|  5 |      99 |  1700 |
|  6 |    1450 |   800 |
|  7 |      88 |     0 |
|  8 |     222 |  5100 |
|  9 |     288 |  5100 |
| 10 |     329 |  5100 |
+----+---------+-------+


mysql> select * from internet;
+----+------------+------+
| id | billing_id | cost |
+----+------------+------+
|  1 |       1450 |  900 |
|  2 |         99 |  900 |
|  3 |        899 |  900 |
|  4 |        329 |  900 |
+----+------------+------+
```

In version `5.5.44-0`:

```
mysql> select distinct cust_id
    -> from billing where billing.cust_id
    -> not in (
    -> select distinct billing_id from internet
    -> );
+---------+
| cust_id |
+---------+
|      34 |
|      12 |
|      88 |
|     222 |
|     288 |
+---------+
```

In version `4.0.24`:

```
mysql> select distinct cust_id
    -> from billing where billing.cust_id
    -> not in (
    -> select distinct billing_id from internet
    -> );
ERROR 1064 (HY000): You have an error in your SQL syntax.  Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select distinct billing_id from internet
)' at line 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, it's unfortunate that you have to work with MySQL 4.0, which is absolutely ancient and did not support most types of subqueries or subselects. You can rewrite your query as a `LEFT JOIN` wherein the `WHERE` clause filters for `NULL` values to indicate a non-match equivalent to the `NOT IN ()`.

```
SELECT
  distinct cust_id
FROM
  billing
  -- Express the equivalence you matched with NOT IN() 
  -- as a left join ON condition
  LEFT JOIN internet ON billing.cust_id = internet.billing_id
WHERE
  -- A NULL value on the joined table indicates
  -- the relationship doesn't exist / there is no matching
  -- `billing_id` record in `internet` for the `cust_id`
  internet.billing_id IS NULL
```

If you are in any position to get a newer MySQL version on that server, it is very highly recommended. The 4.0 release line dates from 2002, early in MySQL's lifetime, and will be missing a great many more important features and security improvements.